# Scalar product of Gaussian random vector with projection matrix is chi-squared

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, chi-squared-distribution

We define the $n$ chi-square random variable this way : if $Z \sim N(0,I_n)$ is multivariate Gaussian random vector, then $\lVert Z \rVert ^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i^2$ (sum of $n$ standard gaussian RV squared) is said to have $n$ chi-square random variable.

Let $H$ be a projection matrix of rank $k \leq n$ and $Z \sim N(0,I_n)$. Show that $Z^T HZ$ is a $k$ chi-square random variable.

$Z^T HZ$ is a 1D random variable so its squared norm is equal to $\lvert Z^T HZ \rvert^2$. We want to show that it can be written as the sum of $k$ standard gaussian RV squared. Since $H$ is a projection matrix of rank $k$, it can be written as $H=U^T D U$ with $D=diag(1,\dots,1,0,\dots,0)$ with k ones and $n-k$ zeros (because rank $k$). It gives $Z^T HZ=(UZ)^TD (UZ)$ and this gives $$\lvert Z^T H Z\rvert =\bigg\lvert \sum_{i=1}^k(UZ)_i^2\bigg\rvert = \sum_{i=1}^k(UZ)_i^2$$

Now I know that $U$ is orthogonal so $UZ \sim N(0,I_n)$ and hence $\lvert Z^T H Z\rvert$ is the sum of $k$ standard gaussian RV squared. However, we are interested in $\lvert Z^T H Z\rvert^2=\bigg( \sum_{i=1}^k(UZ)_i^2\bigg)^2$ which a really something else to treat. How can I deal with this ?

Comment: From a geometric perspective there's nothing to show: as you note, when $H$ is a projection matrix there is a basis in which $H$ is diagonal with $k$ ones and $n-k$ zeros, *QED.*  How to find such a basis? The first $k$ vectors span the image of $H$ and the remainder are orthogonal to its image.  It's unclear how you obtain the stuff in the second half of this post--the sum of squares in $Z^\prime H Z$ obviously is not the sum of fourth powers in your final expression.

Comment: @whuber I am just multiplying things in $Z'HZ$. Imagine for example that $H=I_n$ then $Z'Z=\sum (Z_i)^2$ which is already an $n$ chi square RV. Then $\lvert Z'Z \rvert ^2= (\sum (Z_i)^2)^2$. 

Maybe the product of two chi square RV is also RV with same degree of freedom...

Comment: Why are you squaring this expression??  That has nothing to do with the question you start out with.